# How logrotate behave when there is * and there is one explicit filename in log rotation in one path?

Tags: linux, logrotate, uwsgi

The question is little bit long! Let me explain with the example below. I

have a log-rotation configuration file in `/etc/logrotate.d/` which is used for uwsgi:

```
"/var/log/uwsgi/*.log" "/var/log/uwsgi/*/*.log" {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

Let's say I have about 12 uwsgi modules and I want to keep one the uwsgi app log files more than others so I have a configuration like below:

```
/var/log/uwsgi/app/MY_APP.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 60
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
}
```

Now the question is how should I create log rotate as above and keep `*` for 11 other modules. I don't want to create 11 log rotate with the same configuration, What should I do to overwrite just one module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, logrotate doesn't have an easy way to override an existing glob match of a file. Simply trying to add a more specific match later in the config will give you an error message.

So in order to work around this, there are basically two ways.

**The first one** is the easiest: Put the logs that need a different handling in a different directory. That way, you could even make it easy to change the configuration simply by making an app log to a different directory. Example:

```
"/var/log/uwsgi/*.log" "/var/log/uwsgi/keep05/*.log" {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
}

"/var/log/uwsgi/keep60/*.log" {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 60
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  create 0640 www-data adm
}
```

**A second way** would be to create an **exclusion** in the first glob, the one that matches all 12 logs. But since logrotate doesn't have an easy way to exclude a particular file, you're left with what the regular filename matching library provides - and that's essentially just the one character in the filename. If you make the rule that logs that need to be kept for 60 days must start with a 6, and no other logs may start with a 6, you can do this:

```
"/var/log/uwsgi/*.log" "/var/log/uwsgi/*/[!6]*.log" {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
}

"/var/log/uwsgi/app/6*.log" {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 60
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  create 0640 www-data adm
}
```

I recommend the first version; it'll probably be easiest to keep track of if/when you add more apps.